# Terrified of asking in here, haven't had a problem yet but hoping I can if I get stuck.

Tags: support, allowed-questions, asking-questions

Excuse me if the language is a bit off I'm not a native English speaker. I've been studying(self study) computers and programming for a little over two years, but do not have much education. I've been taking a math class for the last 11 weeks and start an new one next week. I've been using Unix/Linux and Stackoverflow on this network for this time and am pretty terrified at the level the math is in here. I've been browsing questions and can't find any for my level. I'm pretty serious in learning math and have books on Basic Maths, Algebra I, Algebra II, Linear Algebra, Pre-Calculus and Calculus and plan on getting more.

I have sometimes gotten stuck in my learning and Unix/Linux has helped me a lot in the computers.

Can I ask questions here about things where I get stuck at or don't know how to move past a point in my math, at my level? I haven't found anything which says otherwise and also it say's all levels in the help.

The topics of the course I just finished where: Addition/Subtraction, Multiplication, Fractions, Algebra, Equations, Power and Square-root. The course I start at next week is the next step, so pretty much I just learned the basics and I'm starting my math career.

Comment: I found a post related to the level in here. [Is there a lower bound to the level of the questions that can be asked in here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1951/is-there-a-lower-bound-to-the-level-of-the-questions-that-can-be-asked-in-here?rq=1)

Comment: Your command of English is excellent. Is your native language Germanic/Scandinavian ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you, yes Scandinavia: That is Icelandic, the old viking language.

Comment: Ah, Icelandic, the language of those wonderful kennings that Borges liked so much...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taking a look at your StackOverflow questions, I predict your questions here will be well-received.

Generally, any question that expresses an earnest desire to learn and is reasonably scoped can expect a positive response.

For some further site-specific pointers, please see [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Basically, if you clearly state what topic you're currently studying, what your own attempts/ideas are, and what you hope to learn from the thread, your question is bound to be warmly welcomed :).

Answer (score 10):

Questions at every level are welcome.

Just make sure to provide enough detail and context to your question, preferably pinpointing what you are having problems with. Don't just copy-paste textbook assignment.

Have a look, for example at the questions tagged [arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) to get a feeling for what questions are well received, and what are not.